# Cloud firestore sensitive information in .json file

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin, private-key

In official Cloud Firestore documentation we can read that to connect with Cloud Firestore we need to download private key (.json) and use firebase-admin.
Is it safe to use that metod in client app?  Or maybe there is other way to get safe access to Firestore from client app?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe what you perceive specifically to be conflicting advice.  We shouldn't have to fully watch or read other things to understand the issue.  Also describe what your immediate goal is that you're stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

As you said "private key (.json) , firebase-admin". These gives direct access to firestore database without authentication. If you don't want to make your client, admin of your firestore :) Don't do it.

Comment: ok. so can you tell me how can I get access to firestore using authentication?

Comment: Add a rule for authentication. After that use authentication ID in your app to access it. Check the documentation for details. (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it safe to use that metod in client app?

firebase-admin is not meant for use in web and mobile clients.  It's for backend code running in an environment you fully control.  Your users would not have access to this, which means it would be safe for you to use private keys.

You definitely do not want to ship any service account credentials with your app.

> Or maybe there is other way to get safe access to Firestore from client app?

You're supposed to use the provided client SDKs to access Firestore from apps, and use [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to declare which authenticated users are able to read and write which documents.