# Google Firestore client without json credentials file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I need to ship my code in a Docker image to a serverless platform in which I cannot place a creds file.

Typically, I would just copy the `firestore_creds.json` into to the image at build time and run locally, but this isn't the right thing to do when shipping code and is horribly insecure.

Environment variable

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="firestore_creds.json"
```

Python is as such, and the `Client()` just reads from the set env vars on init.

```
from google.cloud import firestore
client = firestore.Client()
```

**How do I go about creating this `Client` without a json creds file present?**

Note: I'd really like to avoid having to place the creds as a json string environment var, then read it, write to a file, and continue. That seems messy and really ugly.

Comment: can you refer to the link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612814/15774176 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107690/15774176 once is it helpful? check this one too : https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082545/15774176

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65612814/15774176)

> In case you have the credentials in memory (environment variable for
> example), and you don't want to create a file especially for it:
>
> ```
> from google.cloud import storage
> from google.oauth2 import service_account
>
> gcp_json_credentials_dict = json.loads(gcp_credentials_string)
> credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(gcp_json_credentials_dict)
> client = storage.Client(project=gcp_json_credentials_dict['project_id'], credentials=credentials)
> ```
>
> Using python3.7 and `google-cloud-storage==1.35.0`

You can also check this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56107690/15774176)

> There is 1 more simpler way of making it working by explicitly
> mentioning Credentials and passing them to the client as shown below.
>
> ```
> import os
> from google.oauth2 import service_account
>
> credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("your-json-path-with-filename.json")
> client = language.LanguageServiceClient(credentials=credentials)
> ```

In order to get more information related to the safe access to Firestore through client App, you can check the [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and [Cloud Firstore Rest API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api)

A Good answer Provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63082545/15774176) related to the safe access as :

> Firebase-admin is not meant for use in web and mobile clients. It's
> for backend code running in an environment you fully control. Your
> users would not have access to this, which means it would be safe for
> you to use private keys.

> You definitely do not want to ship any
> service account credentials with your app.   You're supposed to use
> the provided client SDKs to access Firestore from apps, and use
> [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) to declare which authenticated users are able to
> read and write which documents.

Comment: @pyFiddler Posted an answer is it helpful?